# ext4 hogs lot of unkown space compared to ext3

Tags: 12.04, ext4

Ext4 FS has claimed 3% of partition space. Where has this gone and can I get it reclaimed? I have tried disabling Journals for the ext4 partition. Even this is not helping. Any other tricks I can try to get the space reclaimed other than reverting back to ext3?

```
$ lsb_release -cr 

Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

---

```
df -hP |grep media

/dev/sda3        21G  430M   20G   3% /media/MAIL

/dev/sda2       148G  188M  148G   1% /media/DATA => if I move this to ext4 its claiming 2.4G
```

---

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/MAIL type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)

/dev/sda2 on /media/DATA type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
```

---

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda3 |grep 'Reserved block count'

Reserved block count:     0

$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 |grep 'Reserved block count'

Reserved block count:     0
```

NO hidden files or directories

```
$ sudo du -ah *;pwd

16K lost+found
/media/MAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tune2fs to adjust this, though I would think twice about doing so on /

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1
```

would change the reserved space to 1% on sda1.

Change drive number to suit.

Comment: its already tuned to 0 Reserved block count: 0

Comment: /dev/sda3              20G  172M   20G   1% /media/MAIL
Release: 11.0
Codename: natty
For the older kernel its showing differently.Any settings changed at kernel side??

Answer (score 0):

All my data & archives are on NTFS-COMPRESSED partitions (in the extended partition).  The 'Ubuntus seem trouble-free, in the 'Ubuntu-op systems. Trouble happens when I access these with Windows, or if Linux crashes.  In these cases, only Windows check disk repairs my damaged files.

The Linux equivalent to NTFS-compressed is still in alpha-testing, with no defragging, no disk repair, file-undo, etc. yet available.